# Как исправить ошибку несовпадения размерности в регрессии - "ValueError: dimension mismatch"?

Tags: python, алгоритм, pandas

Я обучил гребневую регрессию с текстовыми данными. Но при прогнозировании появляется ошибка размерности.

Kод, который я использовал для обучения модели:

```
df['FullDescription'] = df['FullDescription'].str.lower()
df['FullDescription'] = df['FullDescription'].replace('[^a-zA-Z0-9]', ' ', regex = True)
df['LocationNormalized'].fillna('nd', inplace=True)
df['ContractTime'].fillna('nd', inplace=True)
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(input='content', encoding='utf-8', 
decode_error='strict', strip_accents=None, lowercase=True, 
preprocessor=None, tokenizer=None, analyzer='word', 
stop_words=None, min_df=6)
X_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(df['FullDescription'])
from scipy.sparse import hstack
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
enc = DictVectorizer()
X_train_categ = enc.fit_transform(df[['LocationNormalized', 'ContractTime']].to_dict('records'))
# <60000x1766 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
#with 120000 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>


Z1 = hstack((X_train, X_train_categ))

# <60000x22510 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
#   with 8475174 stored elements in COOrdinate format>

from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
Y = df['SalaryNormalized']
clf = Ridge(alpha=1.0, random_state=241)
clf.fit(Z1, Y)
```

Загружая выборку для прогноза и просто используя всю выборку для прогноза, но получаю ошибку:

```
Location = r'C:\Users\803008\Desktop\salary-test-mini.csv'
dfT = pd.read_csv(Location)
X_prediction = clf.predict(dfT)
# ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'permanent'
```

Даже если я преобразую переменные по принципу описанному выше, то я получаю ошибку размерности, потому что моя матрица новых признаков для предсказания естественно  меньше исходной:

```
dfT['FullDescription'] = dfT['FullDescription'].str.lower()
dfT['LocationNormalized'].fillna('nd', inplace=True)
dfT['ContractTime'].fillna('nd', inplace=True)
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(input='content', encoding='utf-8', 
decode_error='strict', strip_accents=None, lowercase=True, 
preprocessor=None, tokenizer=None, analyzer='word', stop_words=None)

X_test = vectorizer.fit_transform(dfT['FullDescription'])
enc2 = DictVectorizer()
X_test_categ = enc2.fit_transform(dfT[['LocationNormalized', 'ContractTime']].to_dict('records'))
Z2 = hstack((X_test, X_test_categ))
# <2x264 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
#   with 304 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
X_prediction = clf.predict(Z2)
# ValueError: dimension mismatch
X_prediction = clf.predict(X_test)
# ValueError: dimension mismatch
```

Как исправить ошибку несовпадения размерности (ValueError: dimension mismatch)?

Comment: вы можете выложить куда-нибудь данные, чтобы можно было воспроизвести ошибку?

Comment: [ссылка](https://www.coursera.org/learn/vvedenie-mashinnoe-obuchenie/programming/QFvJY/linieinaia-rieghriessiia-proghnoz-oklada-po-opisaniiu-vakansii) 
@MaxU

Comment: Я на работе, поэтому скинул ссылку. Под заданием 2 файла формата csv. Пока я не нашел возможности на этот сайт загрузить данные.

Comment: [https://yadi.sk/d/Z-9aUHAFtSayg]
[https://yadi.sk/d/viqKcOgXtSazM] @MaxU
Здесь я прикрепил ссылку на исходные данные (первая)
И ссылку на данные по которым нужно проводить тест (dfT)

Comment: df структура
                                         FullDescription LocationNormalized  \
    0      International Sales Manager London ****k  ****...             London
   
    1      An ideal opportunity for an individual that ha...             London
   
    2      Online Content and Brand Manager// Luxury Reta...  South East London   

    3      A great local marketleader is seeking a perman...            Dereham

           ContractTime  SalaryNormalized
  
0        permanent             33000

1        permanent             50000

Comment: мне Yandex не дает скачать эти файлы... Yandex account'а у меня нет

Comment: можно попробовать dropbox?

Comment: да, dropbox должен работать... но должен предупредить - я в machine learning новичек... ;)

Comment: я тоже, но ты помог мне справиться с парой загвоздок и буду признателен тебе за помощь чтобы я мог дальше двигаться.
@ MaxU (https://www.dropbox.com/sh/oa0oggdzyu2m5xz/AABeX51DYq79nT5bhU2R9h8xa?dl=0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вот результат моих жалких потуг:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
from scipy.sparse import hstack

def get_data(filename):
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    df['FullDescription'].str.lower().replace('[^a-z0-9]', ' ', regex=True, inplace=True)
    df['LocationNormalized'].fillna('nd', inplace=True)
    df['ContractTime'].fillna('nd', inplace=True)
    return df

train_fn = r'salary-train.csv'
test_fn = r'salary-test-mini.csv'

train = get_data(train_fn)
test = get_data(test_fn)

# the test DF contains only two rows, so `min_df` should be <= 2 
tfidvect = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=2)
dictvect = DictVectorizer()
clf = Ridge(alpha=1.0, random_state=241)

# train data set
X_train = tfidvect.fit_transform(train['FullDescription'])
X_train_categ = dictvect.fit_transform(train[['LocationNormalized', 'ContractTime']].to_dict('records'))
X_train = hstack((X_train, X_train_categ))

# train the model
clf.fit(X_train, train['SalaryNormalized'])

# test data set
X_test = tfidvect.transform(test['FullDescription'])
X_test_categ = dictvect.transform(test[['LocationNormalized', 'ContractTime']].to_dict('records'))
X_test = hstack((X_test, X_test_categ))

# prediction ...    
rslt = clf.predict(X_test)
```

Результат:

```
In [2]: rslt
Out[2]: array([ 56770.45162297,  37307.74319737])
```

Причина возникновения ошибки описана [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12484310/scipy-and-scikit-learn-valueerror-dimension-mismatch)

Comment: Всё верно, у тебя отлично получается. Ответы правильны и всё работает. Только я не знаю как ты данные загружал?
у меня ошибка была OSError: File b'salary-train.csv' does not exist. Но я по старинке загрузил и сработало. 
Сейчас посмотрю ссылку которую ты скинул. Но мне кажется всё дело было в `min_df` should be <= 2 для тест данных, да?
Должен признать ты ловко владеешь командой def. Попробую разобраться как её применять. Спасибо!

Comment: `salary-train.csv` - должен быть в текущей директории или надо указать полный путь. `min_df should be <= 2` - это по-моему была не основная проблема. Главная "ошибка" была в использовании `fit_transform` вместо `transform` для тестовых данных! Я не понял что ты имеешь в виду под командой `def`?

Comment: понял, что ты имеешь в виду! `def` (от англ. "define") так в питоне начинается декларирование функций...

Comment: Эта команда мне незнакома просто, мне кажется что она дефинирует блок команд и потом применяет его к объекту указанному в начале get_data(filename).

Comment: В этом и правда ошибка и я понимаю что тренировочных данных мы фиксируем вокабуляр, Видимо новые слова которые встречались в тестовом варианте не совпадали....но они же были преобразованы в числовой вектор.